# Embedding the matplotlib toolbar in pyqt4 using matplotlib custom widget

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I have been following this [chapter](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/7900-matplotlib-for-python-developers-sample-chapter-6-embedding-matplotlib-in-qt-4.pdf) to embed a matplotlib Figure into a QTdesigner generated GUI. So far it works, but I need to also embed the toolbar within the GUI to manipulate the plot and save it. How can I modify the example code to add the toolbar? I have googled many sources and they all have their own custom code that does not work with the example given in the book.

I believe I need to modify the custom widget class. The code for the widget class is here:

**Original code (from book):**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()       
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()      
        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)     
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

My question is how can I add code such that the toolbar will display with the canvas?

I know I must import the api using:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

Do I need to create a new class and/or custom widget to put it in?

Comment: Ok, after more fiddling around and looking at [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/qt_mpl_bars.py.txt), I modified the class MplWidget to:  `class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        
        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar)
        
        
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)  
` 
And now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please post that comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after more fiddling around and looking at [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/qt_mpl_bars.py.txt), I modified the class MplWidget to:

```
class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
     def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

And now it works. Thanks!